# ACF вывод максимального и минимального значения в поле

Tags: wordpress, acf

У меня есть произвольный тип постов "post-type-0"
В этом типе постов есть поле = "acf_product_price_usd" Цена
Это поле сделано на ACF

Я пишу фильтр по цене

Мне нужно вывести минимальную и максимальную цену

Как прочитать все посты это типа ='post-type-0'
и прочитать все значения поля = "acf_product_price_usd"

и найти минимальное значение

Answer (score 0):

```
// Получим все записи нужного типа
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post-type-0',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    // Подготовим переменные
    $min_value = false;
    $max_value = false;
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $value = get_field('acf_product_price_usd');
        // Определяем минимальное значение
        if ($min_value === false || $value < $min_value) {
            $min_value = $value;
        }
        // Определяем максимальное значение
        if ($max_value === false || $value > $max_value) {
            $max_value = $value;
        }
    }
}
```